# Do any distributed computing platforms use a common format to exchange messages?

Tags: protocols, terminology, distributed-computing

I'm writing my own toy platform and I'd like to make it compatible with others if possible. Is there a common message format that allows nodes from different platforms to communicate with one another?

**edit**: Added terminology tag for clarity. I've seen the phrase 'exchange format' used to describe what I'm asking for but I don't know whether that is a canonical term.